# "invalid_token" response using Vimeo's "brand new API"

Tags: php, upload, vimeo, vimeo-api

I've started to run Vimeo's PHP code examples available on Github.
I've have registered an app with Vimeo to get client ID, client secret etc and it works ok using the "old" Vimeo API and code examples.

Now, it seems like a good idea to use the new API to be future proof. However when running the basic "index.php" example I get an invalid_token response and running the "upload.php" example gives the response "Unable to get an upload ticket".

I'm pretty sure my client ID, client secret and access token are correct since it works with the old API.

index.php:

```
require_once('../vimeo.php');
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('./config.json'), true);//<- Tokens are stored in a separate file

//$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret']);//<- I tried this first, but the response asked for an access token.
$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);

//$user = $lib->request('/users/dashron');
$user = $lib->request('/me');
print_r($user);
```

Response:"You must provide a valid access token" and "[Expires] => Tue, 30 Apr 2024 14"

upload.php:

```
$lib = new Vimeo($config['client_id'], $config['client_secret'], $config['access_token']);

$files = array("testvideo.mov");//<- Just a test file to try the code example

//   Keep track of what we have uploaded.
$uploaded = array();

//  Send the files to the upload script.
foreach ($files as $file_name) {
    //  Update progress.
    print 'Uploading ' . $file_name . "\n";
    try {
        //  Send this to the API library.
        $uri = $lib->upload($file_name);

        //rest of the code stripped out, but it's identical to the example
```

Response: "Uploading testvideo.mov Error uploading testvideo.mov Server reported: Unable to get an upload ticket. Uploaded 0 files."

Comment: Seems strange that your question has '/users/dashron' in it, and @Dashron is the name of the user that answered...

Comment: I assume he was the one writing the example code from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Access tokens do not transfer between the new and the old API, just your client id and client secret.

There is an "exchange token" endpoint if you have a bunch of pre-saved tokens that need to be converted to API3.

You GET /oauth/exchange using an authenticated OAuth 1.0a request, and we will return an access token response.

If you don't have a bunch of existing users that need to be converted, you can use the OAuth 2 token from your app page, or generate new ones using the [OAuth 2 authentication workflow](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

It might requre special permissions though, so if you run into issues, you should contact Vimeo through https://vimeo.com/help/contact.

Comment: Thanks! Realize I have more to learn. Anyway I got it working by using the access token from the OAuth2 section on my app page for the new API. I had to edit the index.php code example and provide the access token (as mentioned in my post above) otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Half a step forward. Next problem is that I get an "Unable to get an upload ticket" when running the 'upload.php" example. I'm using the same id, secret and token as for the 'index.php' example. Scanning through the vimeo.php code, it seems the status response from requesting an upload ticket is not '200' but rather '201'. Updating vimeo.php to accept a '201' response allows the video to be uploaded.

Comment: Try the new lib, we fixed that very bug last night.